# The connection was reset on wamp

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I have installed `wamp` server on my pc. Then I have installed a zend application. I put it in the *medaffiliate.com* directory in `www` directory. When I access that directory by `localhost/medaffiliate.com` it just shows

```
 The connection was reset
```

I have gone through many answers likes
https://serverfault.com/questions/74313/what-could-cause-an-101-error-in-wamp-under-windows-7

They are all saying about closing `mysql_close($connect);`. My `Apache` error log shows me

```
     [Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6768
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Child 6768: Child process is running
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Child 6768: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Child 6768: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Jul 21 18:35:45 2012] [notice] Child 6768: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1140
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Child 1140: Child process is running
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Child 1140: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Child 1140: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Jul 21 18:36:21 2012] [notice] Child 1140: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 7892
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Child 7892: Child process is running
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Child 7892: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Child 7892: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Jul 21 18:40:39 2012] [notice] Child 7892: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I have found other persons who are facing such problem when they create connection with database. I have created an other project on my www directory and make a connection with database. It is working. But not my project.

I am using `os:window 7. Apache : 2.2.17, PHP:5.3.4, Mysql : 5.1.53`

Comment: Try to disable Antivirus to see if it help, in my case all sites even phpMyAdmin got ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and it was caused by Kaspersky Network Attack Blocker

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem that I could not fix by increasing timeouts and memory limits.

After many hours of trial and error, I finally stumbled upon this other post: https://drupal.org/node/1597820,  which solved the issue for me.

Add the following to the end of httpd.conf to increase the Apache stack size to 8MB.

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8388608
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This solution helped me on Windows 7, WAMP 3.1.4 x64 and it was weird because WAMP version below 3.x.x version didn't had this issue.

Comment: Worked with Windows10 for me WAMPServer 3.1.9

Comment: This worked very well for me on Windows 10. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced this error many times and the solution for me was to increase the apache binary (apache.exe or httpd.exe) stack size. You will need the Visual studio to do that, but you can use the trial version, as I did. You don't even need to turn it on. The command is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64>editbin /STACK:8000000 "c:\Program Files (x86)\WAMP\apache\bin\apache.exe"
```

Change the paths above according to your environment of course.

In the Visual studio directory VC/binary/ there are several utilities by the name editbin.exe. Use the one suitable for you platform or try them one by one, until it works (as I did).