# How fix error POST ... net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea with ckeditor plugins. before, I have no problems using it and the data can be stored properly. but now I get the error "POST" ... path/url ... net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. when I try to enter the process of running a good bit of text. but when I enter a long text and included with some of the code, the error appears. peroses storage I did as follows. p_post.php (form) -> p_post.js (validate) -> f_post.php (insert function).

The following is a script p_post.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var val_holder;
    $("form input[name='btnsubmit']").click(function() { // triggred click
        val_holder      = 0;
        var txtjudul    = jQuery.trim($("form input[name='txtjudul']").val()); // email field

        if(txtjudul == "") {
            $("span.txtjudul_val").html("Judul tidak boleh kosong.");
        val_holder = 1;
        }
        if(val_holder == 1) {
            return false;
        }

        val_holder = 0;

        $("span.validation").html("");

    var datastring = $('#mainform');            
    datastring.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();



      $.ajax({
      url: 'http://example.com/fungsi/f_post.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: datastring.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
      },

                    success: function(e) {
                        if(e == 1) {
                            $("span.txtalert_val").html("Judul, Isi & Tags tidak boleh kosong!!");
                        } else {
                            if(e == 3) {
                                $("form input[type='text']").val('');

                                setTimeout(function(){
                                document.location.reload();
                                },1000);

                                datastring.trigger('reset');
                        }
                        }
                    }
      });
        });
    });
});
```

and no problem with insert function.

Comment: Try to add a timeout to the $.ajax parameters: `timeout: 3600 *5,`.

Comment: What machine is this run on? Windows, Linux? Also, what does the PHP code do? Is there some recursion involved?

Comment: @PunchyRascal I have this issue and there is a lot of recursion involved. How do I solve it?

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel See answers on here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593047/the-connection-was-reset-on-wamp Basically for me, php code did too much recursion (through preg_replace_callback I believe) and it was necessary to edit the apache binary to increase this limit.

Answer (score 2):

Those kind of errors are generally generated in the server. You should check for errors in your server.

If you are using `Windows` with `Apache`, **Event Viewer Application Log** is a good start to gather more info

In `*nix` you should check your **web server log**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a weird error that when there are IP address conflict, somehow AJAX post request can receive this kind of error as well.